Mimicing CHOOSE() function?
Good afternoon! Looking for some advice specific to Postgres. It does not have an equivalent to CHOOSE(), but I would like to use it to pick a random string from a list. I.e.:
 SELECT CHOOSE ('red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green');

Is there an efficient way of replicating this in Postgres? Thanks!
Attempted to use CHOOSE() but it is not present in Postgres nor a known equivalent. Considering using RANDOM() to generate a value and making CASE statements to pick a string based on the value.

If you pass a text array, you can find the length of the array and then generate a random index.

select * from unnest(array['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']) order by random() limit 1;. Incorporate that into a function named choose.

You can use array_sample with a parameter of  1, then take the first value.
select (array_sample(array['red','yellow','blue','green'], 1))[1];

db<>fiddle
